# Why MS access odbc returns numbers but no strings in C#?

Tags: c#, ms-access, unity-game-engine, mono

I'm using an ODBC connection to fetch data from an Access file (.mdb) in a Unity3D environment (Mono.net) on Windows 7 and the connection, deconnection and requests happen without any error.

But when I read the data I get, I only receive the numbers from the database. It can be Integers, or Float numbers. But when I try to fetch a string, it always return an empty string.

Here is what I use in my DataBaseHandler class to perform requests (extracts) :

```
public ArrayList Execute(string req)
{
ArrayList output = new ArrayList();

[...]

cmd = new OdbcCommand(req);
cmd.Connection = accessConnection;

OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read()) {
    String[] row = new String[reader.FieldCount];

    for (int i=0; i<reader.FieldCount; i++) {
        if (!reader.IsDBNull(i)) { // Added if for Visual Studio
            // Getting empties strings, but work fine with numbers
            row[i] = reader.GetValue(i).ToString(); 
            // I was using GetString before, but didn't work with Visual Studio
        }
    }

    output.Add( row );
}

[...]
return output;
}
```

And this is what I perform to test the request :

```
ArrayList data = db.Execute("SELECT * FROM Materials");

foreach (String[] row in data) {
    string line = "";
    foreach (String s in row) {
        line += s + " - ";
    }
    Debug.Log(line); // Logging in Unity3D console
}
```

And I'm getting :

```
1234 - 23.1 - - -
5678 - 12.9 - - -
```

Instead of :

```
1234 - 23.1 - A string - Another string -
5678 - 12.9 - Hello - World -
```

Why am I getting only numbers and no strings and how can I correct it ?

EDIT : It work fine with Visual Studio 12, and Windows 7, and the edits I had to make for making it work with Visual Studio didn't show any improvement in my Unity program.

Comment: If you put a Debug.Log(s); inside your foreach enclosure does it output anything?

Comment: Couple of things, Do not use `ArrayList` use `List<T>`, second use a debug point and debug step by step, Your second code snippet should work fine, the problem is where you are populating your `ArrayList` *(first code snippet)*

Comment: The `Debug.Log` already in the foreach returns something like "302912 - - - 32.1 - - 64 - 50". It skip the strings.
Same result with `List<T>` but I will use break points and see what happens

Comment: I am unable to recreate your issue using C# in Visual Studio 2010. A comment in your code refers to "Unity3D". If you are developing in an environment other than Microsoft Visual Studio and/or working on a non-Windows machine then you really should [edit] your question to mention that.

Comment: I had the Unity3D tag in the question, but it was removed by moderator. I added the mono.net and Unity3D environment in tags and the intro of the question

Comment: It wasn't a moderator, it was a well-meaning member of the SO community who *thought* that Unity3D had nothing to do with it. That remains to be seen. Can you reproduce the issue in Visual Studio on Windows?

Comment: I tried to use this code sample in a Visual Studio project on windows, but somehow I'm not yet able to connect properly to the Access Database I use. It says to me `Data Source name not found and no default driver specified` but the filepath is okay. I'll look further with visual studio, to understand why it's not working right now and maybe it will help me somehow with my issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate the operating system under which you are running. If it is not Windows then also indicate what ODBC components you are using (unixODBC? MDB_Tools? ...?).

Comment: Done : My OS is Windows 7 and I added this information in the question

Comment: Cannot reproduce either.  to state the bloody obvious, be sure that those column in the DB are not empty/DBNull etc

Comment: Of course I have checked that. I also created another DataBase file from scratch with just one table and two simple rows to check if it comes from the database. I tried with a 2000, 2003 and 2007 database file, same issue.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using ODBC instead of OleDB?  Can you read the data from a simple NET app without Unity/mono involved?

Comment: I had troubles using OleDB in my Mono/Unity environnement, and that's why I finally have chosen ODBC. For now, I'm unable tu use ODBC with Visual Studio. I'll try to find out why today.

Comment: Okay, I've been able to use ODBC with Visual Studio. I had to make some changes to the code, and I will edit my first post with comments to show my changes. It works fine with Visual Studio, so the problem come from Unity. Maybe I will try to update the dll I have imported.

Comment: might be obvious, but what is your datatype for he field in your access file? is text and not something like a memo field?

Comment: It is the "short text" Access datatype.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the reader's item directly, i.e.: `row[i] = reader[i].ToString();`

Comment: @Micke : same result with `reader[i].ToString();` : returning numbers, but still no strings.

Comment: Might be a silly comment - but why are you using the String object (capital S) instead of the string primative (lowercase)?

Comment: Hi! Did you try to cast when your expect a string? row[i] = (string)reader[i];

Comment: @vsenik : My first version used a cast for string, but it was not working either. Right now I'm using a MySQL export to make my program work, so I think it's a problem of compability between Mono.net and Odbc, since it works fine with MySQL.

Comment: Could be something tangential, like Unity loading a stale dataset?

Comment: What I personally do is load everything in a DataTable and get the rows accordingly. If you want to do GetString(), that's supposed to work. If it isn't maybe you're not targeting a high enough framework, or just missing a using statement (extension method perhaps?)

Comment: Could you print out the types of reader[i]? Maybe Mono's ODBC implementation is using some funky value type instead of plain old string for text-based fields, and the ToString() method is not implemented properly.

Comment: @DoronAssayasTerre : `Debug.Log( reader[i].GetType() );` gives me System.Int32 and System.String objects types. So it should be working, I guess !

Comment: So it's just returning empty strings. Phooey. Lower level problem then

Answer (score 1):

I have to start by saying that I don't have an environment to reproduce this;  my answer is very much based on what I have expended in C# on Windows with SQL Server; namely that the buffers used underneath the DataReader get reused for memory efficiency.

When the numbers are converted to strings, memory MUST be allocated for the string,  since no string currently exists.  When the ToString is run on an actual string, you are probably getting a reference to a string still buried deep within the DataReader.  That memory then gets reused by the next record.

The basic solution is to either do your processing on a record by record basis,  or make copies of everything you need as you loop around.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use the DataSet instead of ِDataReader When reading data from Access databases!

Answer (score 0):

there are a few bad coding practices [string line = ""; string line=String.Empty;] in there

Output all of **row** before your second foreach statement. you see your problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [GetString(columnOrdinal) method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdatareader.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx) where columnOrdinal is your zero based column of the string.

You need to be specific about the type of the columns being returned when using ODBC. So In your case it would be.

```
public ArrayList Execute(string req)
{
ArrayList output = new ArrayList();

[...]

cmd = new OdbcCommand(req);
cmd.Connection = accessConnection;

OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read()) {
    String[] row = new String[reader.FieldCount];

    for (int i=0; i<reader.FieldCount; i++) {
        if (!reader.IsDBNull(i)) { // Added if for Visual Studio

            if (i > 0 && i < 2)
            {
                row[i] = reader.GetInt32(i);
            }
            else
            {
                row[i] = reader.GetString(i);
            }
        }
    }

    output.Add( row );
}

[...]
return output;
}
```

Otherwise **I believe** GetValue returns a null object.